# How to remove items in the red fruits array inside observable arrays - knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a observable array where I store arrays. I need to use knockout to remove an item in the array. I need to remove an item from the 'redFruits' array inside the 'fruits' array which is inside my observable array.

Here is some code to help show my problem

```js
function viewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.array = ko.observableArray([
        {
            title: "fruits",
            description: "array about fruits",
            redFruits: ["cherry", "strawberry", "raspberry"]
        }
    ])
}
var test = new viewModel();
ko.applyBindings(test);
```

The end output would be that one of the items in the redFruits array is removed

Comment: If you want the UI to update then your redFruits array also has to be an observableArray.

Comment: Something like: `self.array()[0].redFruits.splice(index, 1)` This removes the first object's `redFruits` array's specified index

Comment: What you're showing is  not a valid array and will give you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`.

Comment: @adiga Thanks for the comments. I actually found something on the knockout website which deletes items from an array similar redFruits. 'code'$.each(self.array(), function() { this.redFruits.remove(element) })'code', however this uses JQuery, is there a vanilla way of doing writing this?

Comment: `self.array().forEach(function(fruit) { fruit.redFruits.remove(element); })`

Comment: @connexo That never seemed to work. http://jsfiddle.net/7zmaqc1f/ here is the jsfiddle for some code, there is a delete button for phone numbers which removes them. the self.removePhone is the function I'd like to use, however not with JQuery.

Comment: here is the same jsfiddle but cut down to only have the function I want to work with http://jsfiddle.net/7zmaqc1f/1/

Comment: The example I gave removes one item from the FIRST object's `redFruits` array. `splice` IS vanilla javascript. Why do you need `.each`? Do you want to remove from every object's `redFruits` array? It's unclear what you're asking. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: @connexo Check this JSfiddles http://jsfiddle.net/7zmaqc1f/1/  I basically want to delete the redFruit array items the same way that the code in the JSfiddle delete phone number array items

Comment: @adiga Check this JSfiddles jsfiddle.net/7zmaqc1f/1 I basically want to delete the redFruit array items the same way that the code in the JSfiddle delete phone number array items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your example uses `$.each(self.contacts(), function() { this.phones.remove(phone) })`
this can be replaced by vanilla javascript

```
self.contacts().forEach(function (contact) {
 contact.phones.remove(phone);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4arkv8pc/

or with a for-loop like so

```
var contacts = self.contacts();
for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
 var contact = contacts[i];
 contact.phones.remove(phone);
}
```